# ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1: (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")

Tags: mysql, linux

I have to save my `SQL` query output in a text file. When i run the needed query:

```
mysql -u root -p nextcloud -e "select * from oc_share INTO OUTFILE '/root/sql/test.txt'"
```

..it throws this error:

```
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create/write to file '/root/sql/test.txt' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
```

Why does this happen. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Need more info. With what program are you running the query? What version? etc. Thanks.

Comment: Please share more details. Does the MySQL process have permission to write to `/root`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no access to directory `/root/sql` because of `secure_file_priv`. Please do `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";` and see what directory you can use for `outfile`. This paramater can be set through `my.cnf` or cmd.

```
mysql> show variables like'%secure_file_priv%';
+------------------+-----------------------+
| Variable_name    | Value                 |
+------------------+-----------------------+
| secure_file_priv | /var/lib/mysql-files/ |
+------------------+-----------------------+
```